# Tree complexity using gbm

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart, boosting, hyperparameter

I am using the `gbm` package and I am using the `gbm.step` function. In the `?gbm.step` I see `tree.complexity sets the complexity of individual trees`. Is this equivalent to the `depth` of the tree ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `vignette` by Jane Elith and John Leathwick for GBM's in `dismo`package . The package actually uses `gbm.step` implementation from `gbm` package.

Vignette referes to

> Elith, J., Leathwick, J.R., and Hastie, T. (2008). Boosted regression trees - a
>   new technique for modelling ecological data. Journal of Animal Ecology

This is freely avalaible in the net and says:

> Tree complexity (*tc*) controls whether interactions are fitted: a *tc* of 1 (single decision stump; two terminal nodes) fits an additive model, a *tc* of two fits a model with up to two-way interactions, and so on.

So, it seems it is a `depth` as you supposed.